# Find unique record in RDD[String, String, Double] based on max double value

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I've a RDD[(String, String, Double)] as:-

```
(9W+air-jet-airways-v1,IN,8.0)
(9W+air-jet-airways-v1,ID,7.0)
(9W+air-jet-airways-v1,US,7.0)
(6E+air-indigo-v1,IN,29.0)
(UA+air-united-airlines-v1,US,29.0)
(HO+air-juneyao-airlines-v1,CN,3.0)
(TL+air-airnorth-v1,AU,3.0)
(W3+air-arik-air-v1,NG,7.0)
(CA+air-air-china-v1,CN,6.0)
(6E+air-indigo-v1,NI,3.0)
(CA+air-air-china-v1,CA,2.0)
(LH+air-lufthansa-v1,DE,1.0)
(6E+air-indigo-v1,LK,1.0)
```

Now the required output that I would need is:-

```
(9W+air-jet-airways-v1,IN)
(6E+air-indigo-v1,IN)
(LH+air-lufthansa-v1,DE)
(CA+air-air-china-v1,CN)
(UA+air-united-airlines-v1,US)
```

(irrespective of order) which means first string as a key and based on max value of the double, second string.
I tried something like:-

```
rec.groupBy(x => (x._1)).map{case(k,v) => k}.map(x=> x._2).reduceByKey(_+_)
```

but seems I'm making mistake (obvious mistake in this case is logic to compare)
Since I'm little new to scala and spark, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what is your expected output? and please add some more information about other user as welll and corresponding expected ouput as well. and update with what you have tried so far

Comment: Added the expected output too.

Comment: where's yours attempts? and some more users data?

Comment: This is Spark 101. Have you tried anything ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the output. Not much idea if this is best one but what I tried is:-

```
rec.groupBy(x=>x._1).map{
 case (k,v) =>
 val value = v.toList.sortWith(_._3 > _._3).head
 (value._1, value._2)
}
```

I'm sure there would be some easier way also available but this time it worked for me.